# req.body undefined in MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on my first mean stack application and running in to a problem.  I have a Blog model and I'm trying to assign the properties from the req object but its undefinded.  When I do a console log of the req.body it looks like this:

```
{ '{"title":"some title", "body":"some body", "createdBy":" "created By"}':''}
```

but when I log the values out individually like `console.log(req.body.title)` its undefined.  In my server.js I've included body parser and made sure the route is after incorporating body parser. So at this point I'm not sure why it would be undefined any help is appreciated.

Here is the post for the blog:

```
  createAuthenticationHeaders() {
this.authService.loadToken();
this.httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    authorization: this.authService.authToken
  })
};
```

}

```
newBlog(blog) {    
  this.createAuthenticationHeaders(); // Create headers
  return this.http.post(this.domain + 'blogs/newBlog', blog, 
   this.httpOptions);
}
```

This is the payload
[image]

Thanks

Here is that file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config/database');
const path = require('path');
const authentication = require('./routes/authentication')(router);
const blogs = require('./routes/blogs')(router);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const port = 8080;

mongoose.connect(config.uri, err => {
   if (err) {
      console.log('Connection error db ', err);
   } else {
      console.log('Connected to db ', config.db);
    }
   });


  app.use(
    cors({
     origin: 'http://localhost:4200'
    })
  );

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client/dist/'));
  app.use('/authentication', authentication);
  app.use('/blogs', blogs);

   app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + 
      '/client/dist/index.html'));
   app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I do a console log of the req.body it looks like this:

```
{ '{"title":"some title", "body":"some body", "createdBy":" "created By"}':''}
```

You're posting a JSON, which has another JSON as property, therefore `req.body.title` is undefined. Check your client side, because you're posting the JSON wrong.

```js
// This is what you say you're getting
const bad = { '{"title":"some title", "body":"some body", "createdBy":" "created By"}':''};

console.log(bad);
console.log(bad.title);

// This is what you should post
const good = {"title":"some title", "body":"some body", "createdBy":"created By"};

console.log(good);
console.log(good.title);
```

### Update

You're sending form data, instead of a JSON payload.

use: `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` instead of `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Comment: here is the blog object that I am creating so I"m not sure where its becoming malformed -   onBlogSubmit() {
    const blog = {
      title: this.form.get('title').value, 
      body: this.form.get('body').value, 
      createdBy: this.username 
    };
  }

Comment: How are you posting that blog post?

Comment: Do me a favour, perform the post on the client, and post me a screenshot of the request payload in chrome dev tools.

Comment: added that image

Comment: Ok it's definately a client side problem, give me some minutes and I will explain your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170971/discussion-between-marcos-casagrande-and-troy-bryant).